delete a message only if a specific member uses the command and the message is from someone using discord.py
cant seem to figure this out
code to delete the message, its supposed to only let me delete a specific persons messages, but it doesnt work
async def deletemessage(interaction : discord.Interaction, message : str):
    channel = interaction.channel
    message2 = channel.fetch_message(message)
    if interaction.user.id == userid1:
        if message2.author.id == userid2:
            await message2.delete()

error message:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\app_commands\commands.py", line 828, in _do_call
    return await self._callback(interaction, **params)  # type: ignore
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Colour role assignment bot\main.py", line 66, in deletemessage
    if message2.author.id == userid2:
AttributeError: 'coroutine' object has no attribute 'author'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\app_commands\tree.py", line 1248, in _call      
    await command._invoke_with_namespace(interaction, namespace)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\app_commands\commands.py", line 853, in _invoke_with_namespace    
    return await self._do_call(interaction, transformed_values)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\app_commands\commands.py", line 846, in _do_call
    raise CommandInvokeError(self, e) from e
discord.app_commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command 'deletemessage' raised an exception: AttributeError: 'coroutine' object has no attribute 'author'

expecting it to work, tried everything i can think of, can provide any other code/details if need be

channel.fetch_message is an an asynchronous function, call it using await.
    message2 = await channel.fetch_message(message)

